# Upgrading ruby 1.8.6 to ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some ruby scripts written in `1.8.6`. Now I want to upgrade to `1.9.2` or any other version which is stable.

I have some gems and ruby in-build library in this script so if I upgrade it to ruby `1.9.2` what kinds of problems can I face?

Comment: just upgrade and see what happens. You will get error messages if something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby a lot of us face these types of situations, where upgrading to a newer version could potentially break your code which used to work fine in an older one.

The fantastic Mr. Wayne E. Seguin faced it too, and created a great tool for solving this called **rvm**.

In a nutshell rvm lets you **install different versions of ruby** (1.8.7 or 1.9.2 for example) and easily **switch between these** with a simple

```
rvm use 1.8.7
```

You should go to https://rvm.io/ and learn how to install rvm on your machine. Then you can install both your current ruby version and the one you wish to upgrade to. Switch between the two and test if your scripts are working. This should at least save you some time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

These few are the common ones I come across when upgrading:

If you `require local_file` in 1.8.x you will find that the current directory has been removed from the load path, 1.9.x introduces `require_relative` for this purpose.

Strings can be handled slightly differently.

```
1.9.2 c?
=> c
1.8.7 c?
=> 99
```

In 1.9.2 the Array to string is the same as the 1.8.7 Array.inspect, ie Adds punctuation.

```
1.9.2 [1,2,3].to_s
=> 1,2,3
1.8.7 [1,2,3].to_s
=> 123
```

For the old behaviour in 1.9.2 use `join` for new behaviour in 1.8.7 use `inspect`.

[A review of other changes](http://slideshow.rubyforge.org/ruby19.html#1)