# Can't find Ruby 1.9.2 after installing RVM

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, octopress

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 12.04, and I first installed Ruby 1.9.2.

After I tried installing rvm to use Octopress, `ruby --version` in bash results in `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`

How can I use RVM with ruby 1.9.2?

I don't really understand what RVM is all about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM is a version manager which enables you to decide which of multiple installed Ruby versions you want to use in your current shell session. RVM does this by providing a shell function named `rvm` which can be used to switch between versions in the current session. This changes environment variables, especially the GEM_HOME and PATH, to match the currently selected Ruby installation.

Every installed Ruby version can be selected by a specific identifier string. If you had a system-wide Ruby installation already before you installed RVM, that one should be referenced by the string `system`. The newly installed version in your case should be called `1.9.2`.

To make RVM work as intended, it is necessary to load the `rvm` shell function into your shell. How to do this is described in the [RVM Installation Documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) in section 2 - "Load RVM into your shell sessions as a function".

You can see if the shell function is correctly loaded when the command `type rvm | head -n1` responds with:

```
rvm is a shell function
```

If not correctly loaded it will tell you something like this:

```
rvm is /home/someone/.rvm/bin/rvm
```

If you finally have it working you can switch your active Ruby version with commands like `rvm 1.9.2` or `rvm system`. You can get a list of all Ruby versions and their identifier strings recognized by RVM by the command `rvm list`.

You can also specify which Ruby version shall be enabled in all new shell sessions from the beginning by issuing the following command once:

```
rvm --default 1.9.2
```

Answer (score 3):

The `1.9.2 version` you installed first is not accessible from `rvm`.

While working with `rvm`, only the list of rubies installed through rvm is served. The previously installed versions of ruby - while still present in the filesystem - are not included.

With the steps you have done so far, you have a `1.9.2 version` installed in one location, and a `1.8.7 version` installed as part of `rvm`.

Install `1.9,2 version` by running the `rvm install 1.9.2` command. After that, when you run the `rvm list` command, you should see an output similar to the following:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p358 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

You can switch between different versions of ruby managed by `rvm` with the `rvm use 1.8.7` / `rvm use 1.9.2` commands.

Here's a short blogpost with a good intro to rvm: [Get started right with RVM](http://sirupsen.com/get-started-right-with-rvm/)

Comment: This is not true. RVM supports system Ruby installations. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have not yet switched to the ruby version with:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 (assuming you did rvm install 1.9.2)
```

for a more general explanation I gave [an answer here which might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577123/upgrading-ruby-1-8-6-to-ruby-1-9-2/12580249#12580249).